# How can I use multiple parameters in find?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, find

I need to use find command in my script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
...

find /root/olddir/ -name "*.log" -type f | xargs -I '{}' mv {} /root/newdir/

...
```

But I need to set olddir/newdir and use for multiple dir like this:

```
/root/olddir/ --> /root/newdir/
/root/olddir2/ --> /root/newdir2/
/root/olddir3/ --> /root/newdir3/
/root/another_olddir3/ --> /root/another_newdir3/
/home/old/ --> /home/new/
...
```

Can I use conf file for that? How can I read parameters on conf file like this:

param.conf:

```
#olddir;newdir
/root/olddir/;/root/newdir/
/root/olddir2/;/root/newdir2/
/root/olddir3/;/root/newdir3/
/root/another_olddir3/;/root/another_newdir3/
/home/old;/home/new/
```

Comment: No, `find` does not read any configuration file.  What are you actually trying to do that prevents you from just writing your three commands separately?  And do you really even need find at all?  If all the `*.log` reside directly in directories `/root/olddirN/` then you can just `mv` them directly -- no need for `find` or `xargs`.  The latter are way overkill unless the log files are distributed in a directory tree underneath each `olddirN` (in which case the tree structure will not be copied by your command).

Comment: `while IFS=";" read -r source target; do echo "$source $target"; done < param.conf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never answered my questions, so I am left to guess.  I make the following assumptions:

- the folder lists need to be maintained separately from the script itself, so that it is not feasible to put them directly into the script.
- the pattern of correspondence between old and new directory names is peculiar to the question as posed, such that the script cannot rely upon it
- you are willing to trust the format and contents of the config file

Secondarily, I'll suppose the the command you say you want to execute really is what you want to execute.  If it turns out not to be, then you should be able to adapt my answer to a different command.

The bottom line is that you cannot do what you say with a single `find` command, you need a way to perform multiple `find` commands to your specification.  There are several alternatives, but an embedded `awk` script seems well suited to the problem as you have presented it.  Something like this, perchance:

```
#!/bin bash

# For convenience in case you ever want to change it, read it from
# a command-line argument, etc:
conffile=/etc/logcopy.conf

# The awk script is provided inline as a heredoc.
# Awk is instructed to use a semicolon as field separator as needed for the
# proposed config file format.
# The config file is given as awk's input
awk -F ';' -f - $conffile <<'EOF'

# skip comments
/\s*#/ { next }

# run the given command, where $1 and $2 are the directory names read from
# one line of the config file
{ system("find $1 -name '*.log' -type f | xargs -I '{}' mv {} $2") }

EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

`find` does not accept options from a config file

a single `find` could operate on multiple inputs and move to different locations, but it'd be very convoluted.  it'd be better to write a little bit of shell code to parse the config file and execute the `find` for you.

e.g. something like:

```
CONFIG_FILE="/some/conf"
...
while IFS=';' read -r src dst; do
  find "${src}" -name '*.log' -type f -exec mv {} "${dst}" \;
done <"${CONFIG_FILE}"
```